# My Spring Boot project doesn't work after building a JAR

Tags: java, spring-boot, build, spring-data-jpa, jar

I have never encountered such a problem before. My project, which runs smoothly when I run it with Intellij IDEA, gives the following error when I try to run it locally after building the artifact and generating a JAR:

```
17:30:42.980 [main] WARN org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'newsController' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/akdogan/Downloads/News%20Panel/News-Panel/out/artifacts/News_Panel_jar/News-Panel.jar!/com/istanify/controller/NewsController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'newsService' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/akdogan/Downloads/News%20Panel/News-Panel/out/artifacts/News_Panel_jar/News-Panel.jar!/com/istanify/service/NewsService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManager' defined in class path resource [com/istanify/bean/EntityManagerBean.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManager' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

When I completely remove the injection related to EntityManager from the service, it gives the following error:

```
17:38:49.630 [main] WARN org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'newsController' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/akdogan/Downloads/News%20Panel/News-Panel/out/artifacts/News_Panel_jar/News-Panel.jar!/com/istanify/controller/NewsController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'newsService' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/akdogan/Downloads/News%20Panel/News-Panel/out/artifacts/News_Panel_jar/News-Panel.jar!/com/istanify/service/NewsService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.istanify.repository.NewsRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Thats are my classes and settings:

Controller;

```
package com.istanify.controller;

//imports

@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/news")
public class NewsController {

    private final NewsService newsService;

  //some methods
}
```

Service;

```
package com.istanify.service;


//imports


@Service
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class NewsService {


/*    @PersistenceContext
    private final EntityManager entityManager;*/ manager in comment here
    private final NewsMapper newsMapper;
    private final NewsRepository newsRepository;
    private final TagService tagService;



   //some methods

}
```

Repository;

```
package com.istanify.repository;

import com.istanify.model.concrete.News;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface NewsRepository extends JpaRepository<News,Long> {
}
```

model;

```
package com.istanify.model.concrete;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_news")
public class News {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String newsTitle;

    private String newsContent;

    private String newsSource;

    private String author;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "t_news_tags",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "news_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id"))
    private List<Tag> tags;
}
```

application.yml;

```
server:
  port:  8081
  error:
    include-binding-errors: always
    include-message: always
    include-stacktrace: never

spring:
  config:
    import:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/${task_database}
    username: ${database_username}
    password: ${database_password}
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: true
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    properties:
      '[hibernate.format_sql]': true
  #image
  servlet:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 2MB
      max-request-size: 2MB

logging:
  file:
    name: log/istanify.log
  pattern:
    file: "%d %-5level [%thread]  %logger:%msg%n"
  level:
    '[org.springframework.web]': WARN
    '[org.hibernate]': INFO
    '[org.istanify]': DEBUG

management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: '*'
  info:
    env:
      enabled: true
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: always
    shutdown:
      enabled:  true

info:
  application:
    name: 'Istanify Remote API 1'
    description: 'Istanify Remote API Project'
    version: '@project.version@'
```

pom.xml;

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.15</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.istanify</groupId>
    <artifactId>News-Panel</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>News-Panel</name>
    <description>News Panel project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.5.5.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
        <lombok-mapstruct-binding.version>0.2.0</lombok-mapstruct-binding.version>
        <springdoc.openapi.version>1.6.9</springdoc.openapi.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springdoc.openapi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source> <!-- depending on your project -->
                    <target>${java.version}</target> <!-- depending on your project -->
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok-mapstruct-binding.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

While the project runs smoothly, it seems absurd that it starts causing problems immediately after building. I'm wondering if there might be an issue related to Lombok because there have been no issues during development. As soon as the project turns into News-Panel.jar file, it starts failing to find EntityManager. If I comment it out, it becomes unable to find any repository. I would greatly appreciate it if someone who knows could help. I am currently experiencing this issue with all of my projects. Thank you.